# Analyze a C expression from a lexical analysis perspective

Tags: c, token, tokenize, lexical-analysis

So I am coding a lexical analyzer program(in `PHP`) as homework and I have to tokenize a `C` program.

I have this following piece of code from the `C` code I have to analyze:
`+e25.f12.e--` which would then tokenize into `OPERATOR => +`, `VARIABLE => e25` but skips `.f12.e--` because it signals it as an error. Now I am not sure if that is the correct behaviour, is the algorithm working properly or it should tokenize that too(if it should, can you please show the tokenization of `.f12.e--` ?).

For example, the following code should tokenize as follows:

Code:

```
xe,12.34e-25" ;;kjk 'a'"'"'/*  dfh sfg fsg 
   sdgf sdf






 sdfvvs  svd sdv
 *//*3rf 3rfg 3f



 e2f2efef*//*/*/*/
```

Tokenization:

```
var => xe
operator => ,
constant => 12.34e-25
string => " ;;kjk 'a'"
string => '"'
operator => *
operator => /
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
+e25.f12.e
```

tokenises as:

```
+ operator
e25 identifier
. operator
f12 identifier
. operator
e identifier
```

Comment: I see, I was thinking the same but wasn't sure about `.`, what type of operator is `.` in `C` ?

Comment: It is the structure-member operator. You should have a complete list of operators and special characters before you start this project.

Comment: I see, thank you!
@EJP yeah, I have searched everywhere, can't find one.